# Passing click function from One component to other component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

In React material ui i am having two components where i am calling save function on button click, is it right way or not can anyone suggest the better way:

```
    const callback = {};
 return (
    <>
      {!state?.creditCard?.isSaved ? (
        <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paymentContainer}>
          <Box className={classes.subPaymentContainer}>
            <Typography className={classes.title}>Card Payment</Typography>
            <CardPaymentForm
              callback={callback}
              validationPassed={() => actionsCollection.booking.saveCard(true, state.creditCard.lastFourDigits)}
              formType="profileForm"
            />
            <div>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                onClick={(e) => callback.saveCard(e)}
                value="SAVE CREDIT CARD"
                className={classes.button}
              />
              <div style={{ display: "flex", marginTop: 20 }}>
                <img className={classes.lockIcon} src={lockIconInfo} alt="" />
                <Typography className={classes.paymentInfo}>
                 
                  <Link href="/terms" target={"_blank"}>
                    Terms of Payment
                  </Link>
                  .
                </Typography>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Box>
        </Paper>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ height: 373 }}>
          <CardStored removeCard={removeCard} />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

in CardPayementForm below calling the save function below is the code:

```
const CardPaymentForm = ({ classes, callback, validationPassed, formType, lastFourDigits }) {
 useEffect(() => {
    callback.saveCard = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
     =
      if (validateForm()) {
      =
        validationPassed();
      }
    };
      });
}
```

here without callback  how to call save function directly in cardpaymentform, Any help please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will apply to your problem but if you had a `component_a`
like

```js
const ComponentA = ({handleClick}) => {

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick(e => handleEvent(e))>
        Click here
      </button>
    </>

}
```

and a `component_b`

```
const ComponentB = () => {

 const handleClick = (e) => {
   // do something with the event from component a 
 }

  return(
    <>
      <ComponentA handleClick={handleClick}/>
    </>
    )

}
```